# Automate lines creation inside rectangles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, autocad

I am using Illustrator in order to create rectangle shapes. I am willing to insert rows inside each rectangle. Each rectangle suppose to have different number of rows. What would be the best approach to attack it? 
(I am creating seating charts and want to draw the rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a rectangle shape with the rectangle tool, and click `Object` > `Path` > `Split Into Grid`.

[image: Screenshot of Split Into Grid dialog]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Billy's excellent answer, there is also the **Rectangular Grid Tool** which offers a less definitive, more "free form", method of creating a collection of boxes.

[image]

[image]

With the mouse held down, tap the **arrow keys** on the keyboard to change the number of divisions.

Or just simply "click" once on the artboard with the tool to show it's options:[image]